# Using Firebase v3 Java Libraries from Clojure Hangs

Tags: firebase, clojure, firebase-realtime-database, credentials

Reading or writing to Firebase v3 from Clojure via the Java/Android Firebase libraries as per [mrmcc3's usage](https://github.com/mrmcc3/firebase-wrappers/blob/master/firebase-clj/src/firebase/core.clj) hangs. I suspect a credential issue, but see no errors. [matchbox](https://github.com/crisptrutski/matchbox/blob/master/src/matchbox/core.cljc) makes similar calls using an older `com.firebase.client` library, if that makes a different.

#### Maven Dependency

```
[com.google.firebase/firebase-server-sdk "3.0.3"]
```

I downloaded the service account credentials and massaged it into a `FirebaseDatabase` instance, which I can call `(child (ref db) "some-key")` on to get coherent database URLs.

However, any calls to actually that read (via value or child listener), set, or push new data hangs.

### Hanging Code

```
(let [db-name "my-db"
      creds   (io/input-stream "service-account-creds.json")
      opts    (options "https://my-db.firebaseapp.com/" creds)
      app     (get-or-init db-name opts)  ; (get-app "[DEFAULT]")
      db      (app->db app)
      root    (ref db)]
    (def prom (get (child root "some-key"))))

prom
=> #object[clojure.core$promise$reify__7005 0x4f7066a6 {:status :pending, :val nil}]

;; sanity check DB:
(app->db app)
=> #object[com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
    0x1580407f
    "com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase@1580407f"]

=> Promise never resolves:
@prom  ;; hangs forever
```

I suspect something related to credentials, but with no user feedback, it's impossible to debug. I attempted to solve this for several hours - most official documentation appears [deprecated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start) or links to 3 year-old libraries.

I am able to read and write to this Firebase database from JavaScript/ClojureScript just fine - rules allow all writes.

What am I doing wrong?